# Using Morgan and Winston for logging - files are being generated but are blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

Here is my code:

```
var logDirectory = __dirname + '/log';

//ensure log directory exists
fs.existsSync(logDirectory) || fs.mkdirSync(logDirectory);

//create a rotating write stream
var accessLogStream = FileStreamRotator.getStream({
filename: logDirectory + '/access-%DATE%.log',
frequency: 'daily',
verbose: false
})

// setup the logger
//app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}))
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: logger.stream}))




/*********************************************************************/


//This is 404 for API requests - UI/View 404s should be 
//handled in Angular
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

app.set('port', 5050);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
//debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

All the necessary dependencies are being reference and the code references a logger.js file which includes the following code:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.emitErrs = true;

var logger = new winston.Logger({
transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
        level: 'info',
        filename: './logs/all-logs.log',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false
    }),
    new winston.transports.Console({
        level: 'debug',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true
    })
],
exitOnError: false
});

module.exports = logger;
module.exports.stream = {
write: function(message, encoding){
    logger.info(message);
}
};
```

Files are being generated and the file names are timestamped.
Why do my log files have nothing in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in place of

`app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: logger.stream}))`

try using

`app.use(morgan('default', { 'stream': logger.stream}));`

This should just write the resource and requested and the Browser Info along with a timstamp to your `all-logs.log` file.

Comment: I get this message which is why I used combined: "morgan deprecated default format: use combined format main.js:87:9"  The files are still blank.

Comment: if you insert an explicit `logger.info('This is a log entry');` does that actually insert into your log then?

Comment: I mean it seems pointless to suggest this but do you definitely have write permissions to that file?

Comment: It's a legitimate question and yes I do have write access to the files.

Comment: However the log folder is being set to read-only.  I unset it and it resets it right back.

Comment: If you do a `fs.access(logDirectory, function(err) { console.log(err ? 'no access' : 'can access'); });`   after   `fs.existsSync(logDirectory) || fs.mkdirSync(logDirectory);` what's the output?

Comment: the output is: can access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92086/discussion-between-webdev5-and-peteb).

Answer (score 0):

The winston.log won't use your transports
logger.info('test'); will log test to both the console and the file since those are your defined transports.
Is your 'logger' located in a separate .js file or the same as your express server?
Here is my full logger.js file that I use in my express implementations:

https://gist.github.com/pbaio/ac934a06b91b99be6526

I would put that in a separate file in your parent directory such that you would reference it in your server file as such: 
var logger= require('..logger.js');

then I would incorporate it as you do now in your middle:

```
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: logger.stream}));
```

I would also delete your logs directory and have the app stop creating the directory all together, then I would recreate the log directory manually
I would imagine that should remedy your entire issue

Comment: This is peteb's solution he posted in chat which worked.